# List of powers in Bash?

Tags: bash

I have a variable holding a list of exponents:

```
p=`seq -1 0.25 2`
```

I want to obtain from this a list of powers of 10, and assign it to another variable. In this case the expected result would be:

`0.1, 0.177828, 0.316228, 0.562341, 1., 1.77828, 3.16228, 5.62341,
10., 17.7828, 31.6228, 56.2341, 100.`

How can I do this?

Comment: "In a variable"? What kind of variable? A string, with embedded separators (spaces or otherwise) to make it smell vaguely array-ish? A native shell array? Something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ answers=`seq -1 0.25 2 | sed 's/^/e(/; s/$/ * l(10))/' | bc -l`  
$ printf '%s\n' $answers  
.10000000000000000000
.17782794100389228012
.31622776601683793320
.56234132519034908039
1.00000000000000000000
1.77827941003892280121
3.16227766016837933197
5.62341325190349080387
9.99999999999999999992
17.78279410038922801203
31.62277660168379331945
56.23413251903490803828
99.99999999999999999840
```

Comment: ...btw, if you wanted to print three to a row, that'd be `printf '%s %s %s\n' $answers`. For more control over exactly how they're printed, you can use standard format strings like `%.08f` rather than `%s` to control precisions, &c.

Comment: ...or, if you wanted to read your answers into an array and expand that array (thus ensuring that you can't get messed up by globs &c), one might consider `readarray -t answers < <(seq -1 0.25 2 | sed 's/^/e(/; s/$/ * l(10))/' | bc -l)`, and then `printf '%s\n' "${answers[@]}"`; no glob expansion or string-splitting there, thereby squashing bugs that might be caused by data that can be expanded as a glob or split into multiple arguments in manners other than those intended.

Answer (score 3):

Using gnu awk you can do this:

```
L=$( LC_ALL=C seq -1 0.25 2 | awk '{print 10**$1}' )
echo $L

> 0.1 0.177828 0.316228 0.562341 1 1.77828 3.16228 5.62341 10 17.7828 31.6228 56.2341 100
```

(I needed the `LC_ALL=C` due to my regional settings.)